# EU Permit after wedding, previously refused Marriage visitor visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, eu, family, entry-permit

Previously received some great input on here, so back again.

My partner is a EEA citizen and I'm from India. We met while we were students in the UK and have been in a relationship since. Earlier this year, we applied for a marriage visitor visa so we can get married in the UK. However, this got rejected as they stated a job offer letter that I attached was not genuine, which is not the fact, and I have proof confirming this from the company as well.

Post the refusal my partner and I decided to get married in India, and we had a brief religious ceremony and got the the marriage certificate from the registrar, I have also got it apostilled.

Now that I'm going to apply for a EEA permit, do you think I should submit the documents to counter the refusal? (On the online application, I have explained the situation when asked for travel history and refusals)

We have also gathered enough evidence like photos, screenshots of texts and hotel/flight bookings of our travels together of two years to prove that it is a genuine relationship, as I have read about many refusals due to this reason.

Comment: Are you planning to settle in the UK?

Comment: Yes, we plan to live there for 2 years until my husband completes his ongoing project. I will also be working meanwhilee.

Comment: Also why would you want to counter the refusal of the marriage visitor visa?  You've gotten married in the meanwhile.  You're no longer qualified for a marriage visitor visa, nor do you have any use for one.  Was the job offer in the UK? If it was then you probably would have been refused even if they had concluded that the offer was genuine, since it would have been evidence that you weren't a visitor.

Comment: Well, I was asking if there is a need for countering. We are applying for EEA Family Permit now that we are married. Would there be a need to address and counter previous refusal on this permit application?

Comment: Your employment status is not relevant to an EEA family permit.

Comment: Alright, so I am interpreting that there is no need to address previous refusal in my EEA family permit application.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would (of course) mention the refusal when asked.  I would not address the validity of that refusal, nor of the evidence on which it was based, unless asked.

For an EEA family permit, you're only supposed to have to establish a limited number of facts:

1. Your identity,
2. The EU, EEA, or Swiss nationality of your family member,
3. Your relationship to your family member, and
4. That your family member either

   - has been in the UK for less than three months or
   - is a "qualified person."

Because your marriage is relatively recent, it is a good idea to include the evidence you mention showing the history of your relationship.  Aside from that, all you should have to show are the documents needed to establish the above facts:

1. Your passport,
2. Your spouse's passport or national ID card,
3. Your marriage certificate, and
4. Evidence showing that your spouse is employed in the UK.

Comment: Thank you for all your advice. I submitted it on the 23rd, so should be receiving a reply within the next 3 weeks, I have included all the documents that you mentioned, hopefully all goes well. I will keep you updated on the outcome.

Comment: Hi everyone, I just collected my passport with the EEA permit stamp. Partner and I are super excited :)

Comment: @Pri95 congratulations. If you have time to post an answer describing the details of your successful application, it would be useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to let you know of the successful outcome of my application. We are both very excited and finally get to live together under one roof.

Here is some info about my application, hope this helps!

So I filled out the application under Other Non-Settlement visa from the UK government website. I included information regarding our circumstances, long-distance relationship and meeting in the UK as students four years ago, details of our vacations in the past. **It was critical that I added the information regarding my previous refusal, however, I did not go about countering it, I only mentioned that there was a refusal due to X reason and that I will be happy to submit supporting documents during any intervention from UKBA in the future**.

Here are the documents that I submitted :

- Passport
- Marriage certificate with apostille stamp
- National IDs, mine and his
- ILR document(Husband is from Cyprus and recently applied for ILR due
  to Brexit)
- Payslips of my partner
- Employment contract of my partner
- Rental contract of my partner in the UK
- Photos of our wedding and vacations, I submitted 15 photographs
- Chats screenshots of 2 years, I submitted 50 screenshots
- Hotels and flight bookings of our vacations

Submitted application - 23 May
Received passport back with stamp - 12 June (Received call one day prior for collection)
No of working days : 14